# How to update a field in Array of data in Firebase realtimedatabase using Firebase Functions in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firbase realtime database operations.This is my json

```
"machines":[{
    "machinecode":"val",
    "productsloaded":[
        {
            "pricecategory": "0.5",
            "totalload": "10",
            "lastloaded": "0",
            
         
        },
        {
           "pricecategory": "1",
            "totalload": "10",
            "lastloaded": "0"
         
        },
        {
           "pricecategory": "1.5",
            "totalload": "10",
            "lastloaded": "0"
         
        },
        
        {
            "pricecategory": "2",
            "totalload": "10",
            "lastloaded": "0",
         
        }
}]  
            
        }],
```

firebase db is look like this

```
machines
    ---- 0
           ---machinecode='value'
           ---productsloaded
                 ---0
                     ---pricecategory:''val'
                     ---totalload:'val'
                     ---lastloaded:'val'
                  ---1
                     ---pricecategory:''val'
                     ---totalload:'val'
                     ---lastloaded:'val'
                  ---2
                     ---pricecategory:''val'
                     ---totalload:'val'
                     ---lastloaded:'val'
```

I want to update the totalload and lastloaded fields based on the pricecategory.I tried to access the values of the child "productloaded" like this

```
prd= FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("machines").orderByKey().equalTo("productsloaded");
```

But i am not able to update the fields with this reference"prd".What is the solution for this?

Comment: There are multiple `productloaded` properties in the JSON you shared. 1) Which of these do you want to update? 2) How can we know in the code which one needs to be updated?

Comment: is it normal that you have pricecategory and productcategory? Shouldnt you correct that so they match?

Comment: sorry..it's pricecategory ,not productcategory.

Comment: i want to update totalload and lastloaded  properties of the productloaded based on the pricecategory